# pentaho, spoon: how to validate text file content and move file after processing

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am doing a work for a master with pentaho and I would like to know hot to di something.

I receive a text file that I have to validate the content(type, lenght,..), if the content is correct the file is proccesed but if there is any bad field I have to wirte  in a log an then move the file to othe folder without processing any row.
Now, I have got that a text input file have an error when a type field is not correct but I cant treat it.

Does anyone a sg¡uggestion how to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in a job (all the steps of a transformation start in parallel, so you may move the files before they are read).

In this job, you first execute the `Transformation` which 'Set file to result`if and only if the file have to be moved. The next entry on the job is a`Move File`with the`Copy previous result to args` checked.